# search for a dictionary key value using wildcard

Tags: python

There is any way to use a wildcard in order to skip a dictionary key.
I have the following nested dictionary:

```
{'1': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:788 ', 'payload':' ****AAAA** **\n****'}, 
'2': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:881 ', 'payload': ****'BBB**\n\n**'}, 
'3': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:897 ', 'payload': ' ****CCC**\n**'}, 
'4': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:907 ', 'payload': ' ****DDD** \n**'}}
```

And i want to ignore the first keys 1, 2 .... and extract only the value corresponding to payload key.

is possible to use some kind of wild card like i tried below?

```
for i in data['*']['payload']:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `for i in data.values(): print(i['payload')`

Comment: Thank you Brown Bear, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

simply iterate over it

```py
for k1 in d:
    for k2 in d[k1]:
        payload = d[k1][k2]
        print(k2,'>>', payload)
```

output

```
date >> 25-Jan-21 12:45:15:788 
payload >> ****AAAA** **
****
date >> 25-Jan-21 12:45:15:881
payload >> ****BBB**

**
date >> 25-Jan-21 12:45:15:897
payload >> ****CCC**
**
date >> 25-Jan-21 12:45:15:907
payload >> ****DDD** 
**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'1': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:788 ', 'payload':' ****AAAA** **\n****'}, 
'2': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:881 ', 'payload': ' ****BBB**\n\n**'}, 
'3': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:897 ', 'payload': ' ****CCC**\n**'}, 
'4': {'date': '25-Jan-21 12:45:15:907 ', 'payload': ' ****DDD** \n**'}}

for el in d.values():
    print(el['payload'])
```

Or:

```
print([el['payload'] for el in d.values()])
```

You can iterate over the values in the directory using `.values()`. From there, you can access `payload` rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the first two values of a list you would tipically do `lst[2:]`, but `data.values()` isn't a list, so we need to turn it into one using `list(data.values())`:

```py
for value in list(data.values())[2:]:
    print(value['payload'])
```

(The same can be done with `data.items()` if you need access to the key)
**Output:**

```
 ****CCC**
**
 ****DDD** 
**
```